# How to deploy to AWS Lambda quickly, alternative to the manual upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am getting started with writing an Alexa Skill. My skill requires uploading a .ZIP file as it includes the `alexa-sdk` dependency being stored in the node_modules folder.

Is there a more efficient way to upload a new version of my Lambda function and files from my local machine without zipping and manually uploading the same files over and over again? Some like git push or a different way to deploy via Terminal with a single command?

Comment: I recommend checking out the Apex framework. http://apex.run/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [update-function-code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html) CLI command.

Note that his operation must only be used on an existing Lambda function and cannot be used to update the function configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Khalid's answer, I recently created this rudimentary batch script to ease a particular lambda function's deployment. This example is for a NodeJS Lambda function which has it's dependencies located in the `node_modules` folder.

#### Prerequisits:

Have 7zip installed. Found [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)

Have it available in CMD (have it on system PATH variable) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122732/unzip-files-7-zip-via-cmd-command)

Have your local aws-cli set up with valid credentials that have access to uploading to AWS Lambda.

```
rm -rf target
mkdir -p target

cp -r index.js package.json node_modules/ target/

pushd target

7z a zip_file_name.zip -r
popd

aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME \
    --zip-file fileb://target/zip_file_name.zip \
    --region us-east-1
```

Answer (score 0):

My one-liner for bash:

```
zip -u f.zip f.py; aws lambda update-function-code --zip-file fileb://f.zip --function-name f
```